# How to view a README.md file saved in Google Drive?

Tags: markdown, drive, webarchive

I have saved a readme.md file from GitHub in a Google drive as a webarchive file. I was planning to share it to others. After uploading, I am unable to open it. Says No preview available. I am not seeing any connected apps as well. Any suggestions.